# Where did "Chinchew" come from?

Tags: pronunciation, romanization

There is this Chinese city called 泉州. Mandarin: Quánzhōu. Cantonese: Cyun4-zau1. Hakka: Chhièn-chû. Min Nan: Chôan-chiu. [Pronunciations found here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B3%89%E5%B7%9E). Wikipedia adds a local Hokkien: Chôa<sup>n</sup>-chiu. [Here](http://www.mogher.com/dic/search/%E6%B3%89%E5%B7%9E) I get Teochew: Zuan5-ziu1. Couldn't find Min Dong or Gan or other dialects, but those shouldn't matter. Postal romanization: Chinchew. Now, "chew" obviously renders the "chiu" of Min Nan and/or "ziu" of Teochew. But where did that "chin" come from? Is the postal romanisation a weird hybrid of a misheard Cantonese "cyun" (misheard as *cin and spelled chin consequently) and a correctly heard Min Nan / Teochew "ciu"/"ziu" or is there more to this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postal_romanization says
    Local dialect may be used:  Chinchew (Quanzhou), you probably need to look at 泉州话 http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=Org1c0LujgzEmHAR8fjXV_kSZR_xpeFJeosg991WFv-nMpc7aijCy5crkFeUmtRpuYfIEvUUEFKiWHgsFW4zHgmUhevd7bssEcsYWZAapUYCyJfC0yp3kAAcESkbBZbR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[泉州，簡稱泉或鯉，又稱刺桐城、清源、溫陵。](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%89%E5%B7%9E%E5%B8%82)
Although 清 can be transliterated as chin, it does not seem to be the reason.

[Quanzhou, formerly known as Chinchew.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanzhou)
The Postal Map name of the city was (note: should be "is") "Chinchew", a variant of Chincheo, **the Portuguese and Spanish transcription of Chiāng-chiu**.
It is uncertain when or why British sailors first applied the name to Quanzhou. Variants include Kangiu, Chinchu, and Chincheu.

所以，Chinchew 是從葡萄牙語、西班牙語的 Chiāng-chiu 轉譯而來。

Comment: More precisely, it probably stems from the Quanzhou pronunciation of Zhangzhou, which, according to [the Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/漳州), is "Tsing-tsiu".

Comment: Looked up Zhangzhou because the Wiki page you linked (the English one) mentioned Zhangzhou as "the major port trading with Macao and Manila in the 16th and 17 centuries".

Comment: So, Chinchew was used by 漳州 first, and then "stolen or robbed" by 泉州 till today. 漳州 became Changchow first, and then Zhangzhou. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

the internet archive has a copy of the book "the city of springs: or, mission work in chinchew", which is published in the year 1902:

https://archive.org/details/princeton_theological_seminary_3720_0539

on page 25, it stated:

> The name Chinchew, now so familiar to us, is merely an anglicised 
>   form of Tsuien-chow, being the northern or mandarin pronunciation 
>   of the name. In the Amoy language it is pronounced Tsoan- 
>   chiu. Tsoan — spring or fountain, and chiu — a city whose resident 
>   mandarin ranks as a prefect. The whole may be translated City of 
>   Springs.

[image]

it's an very interesting book, with numerous illustrations, have a read if you're not in that "area". well, internet archive is blocked in . . . :(